# How to convert Symbol to Number?

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, matrix, manipulate, argument-patterns

### Question

I have a variable `x` which is associated with the number 1 : `x= 1`

In the program, I faced with the data type problem that `x` is evaluated as a `Symbol` but not a `Number`(integer ,double, etc).
(The detail of the problem is written in `Background  -> My trial` section below.)

Not being familiar with the specification of Wolfram language, I'm naively thinking of solving this by converting the `Symbol` to `Number` using some standard function of Mathematica. However, I cannot find it.

Is it possible?

Any information would be appreciated.

### Background

I want to make a function for fetching a value from some array by designating the entry(index) in mathematical style.

For example, I want to have a function `fetchValue` like this:

```
field1 = {{5,34,7},{9,77,11}}; (**)
field2 = {2,3,8,8,4,20,7,0,3}

fetchValue[{1,2},field1] (* expected return: 34 *)
fetchValue[{5},field2] (* expected return: 4 *)
fetchValue[{55,1},field1] (* expected return: "Reference error. Check out the range of the array." *)
fetchValue[{3,1,5,4},field1](* expected return: "Reference error. Check out the dimension of the array." *)
```

#### My trial

Let me say we have the following two arrays:

- the array `field` whose dimension is unknown(say `d`) and the size is `n^d`
- the array `position` whose dimension is 1 and the size is `d` (the same with dimension of `field`)

Now, we want a function named `fetchValue` which takes

- argument1 `position` : size `d` array (if `d` = 2,  `position` = {2,5},{12,6},...)
- argument2 `field`: size `n^d` array

```
fetchValue[position_, field_] := (
    width = Length[field];height = Length[field];
    dimension = Depth[field];
    index = 1;
    
    ret = field;
  
  While[level <= dimension,
   index = position[[level]];
 
   IF[1 <= index <= Length[ret], 
      ret = ret[[index]], Return["Range is wrong"]
    ];
 
   level++;
 ]

    Return [ret];
   );
```

This exactly returns the target entry of the field, but the data type of it is somehow a `Symbol`, not a `Number`, meaning I have to look for the way to convert `Symbol` to `Number`.

### Further background

I'm in a project of calculating some fields on a discrete lattice and trying to use Mathematica.

The fields are not given as a analytical function, but all formed by computer calculation.

The fields are managed by array(list). So, if we want value of lattice point (1,2,5), we get the value by `field[[1]][[2]][[5]]`.

What I want is to make it easy to get access to the value of field on a certain lattice point like
`field[{1,2,5}]`.

Comment: `fetchValue[spec_, arr_]:= arr[[##]]& @@ spec`? or `fetchValue[{spec__}, arr_]:= arr[[spec]]`?

Comment: Thank you. It worked.

Comment: What I wanted is the former one. It worked. Thank you.